# Determine the value $f(-1)$ where $f$ is an analytic continuation of a series.

Tags: complex-analysis

Question: The series $\sum^\infty_{n=1}\left(\frac{2z}{z+1}\right)^n$ converges in some neighborhood of $0$ to a function that admits an analytic continuation $f(z)$ to a neighborhood of the point $-1$. Determine the value $f(-1)$.

My try: Define 
$$
f(z)=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\left(\frac{2z}{z+1}\right)^n.
$$
Then $f(-1)$ should equal
$
\lim\limits_{a\rightarrow -1}f(a).
$
However, I don't know how to find value of 
$$
\sum^\infty_{n=1}\left(\frac{2a}{a+1}\right)^n
$$
where $-1<a<0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a geometric sum and its value is $\frac {2z/(z+1)} {1-2z/(z+1)}=\frac {2z} {1-z}$. The limit of this as $z \to -1$ is $-1$.